# what is the assert keysize doing here

Tags: python

```
def encryptData(key, data,mode=AESModeOfOperation.modeOfOperation["CBC"]):
    """encrypt `data` using `key`
    `key` should be a string of bytes.
    returned cipher is a string of bytes prepended with the initialization
    vector.
    """
    key = map(ord, key)
    if mode == AESModeOfOperation.modeOfOperation["CBC"]:
        data = append_PKCS7_padding(data)
    keysize = len(key)

    assert keysize in AES.keySize.values(), 'invalid key size: %s' % keysize

    # create a new iv using random data
    iv = [ord(i) for i in os.urandom(16)]
    moo = AESModeOfOperation()
    (mode, length, ciph) = moo.encrypt(data, mode, key, keysize, iv)
    # With padding, the original length does not need to be known. It's a bad
    # idea to store the original message length.
    # prepend the iv.
    return ''.join(map(chr, iv)) + ''.join(map(chr, ciph))
```

Comment: Can you speak to explain your problem ? Have a look on how [StackOverflow works](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question please.

Comment: It's asserting that the value of `keysize` is one of the values in `AES.keySize`.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
assert keysize in AES.keySize.values(), 'invalid key size: %s' % keysize
```

checks that the length of the `key` argument is in its allowed values, and will throw an `AssetionError` with the message "invalid key size: `keysize`" if it isn't.

> - `key` (bytes/bytearray/memoryview) –
>     The secret key to use in the
>     symmetric cipher.
>
> It must be 16, 24 or 32 bytes long (respectively for AES-128, AES-192
>   or AES-256).

**[Source](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/aes.html)**